# How to Get the first value of same element in Json

Tags: json

I want to pick the first value of 'Code' element from following Json Payload. I am using following website to try this out. http://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/

**Json Payload:**

```
   {
    "TotalAccounts": {
        "Account": [
            {
                "Code": 123,
                "Account": {
                    "Name": {
                        "Initials": null
                    },
                    "Address": {
                        "Street": "ABC"
                    }
                },
                "ContactInformation": {
                    "Email": "ABC@gmail.com"
                },
                "DunningLevelCode": "R0"
            },
            {
                "Code": 456,
                "Account": {
                    "Name": {
                        "Initials": null
                    },
                    "Address": {},
                    "CustomFields": null
                },
                "ContactInformation": {
                    "Email": "ABC@@gmail.com",
                    "Phone": null,
                    "Mobile": null,
                    "Fax": null
                },
                "DunningLevelCode": "abc"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The Json path i am using is below:

```
$..Code
```

**Result:**

```
[123,456]
```

**Expected Result:**

```
[123]
```

Need help.

Comment: you should be able to access the first value like so `data.TotalAccounts.Account[0].Code`

Comment: or simply $..Code[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this you will get the output

```
$..Account[0].Code
```